# PHP function for removing &nbsp and skip a line

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to erase &nbsp in Wordpress post when we skip a line but keeping the "skip a line".

In post.php I've added this function :

```
function remove_empty_lines( $content ){
    $content = preg_replace("/&nbsp;/", "\n", $content);
  return $content;
}
add_action('content_save_pre', 'remove_empty_lines');
```

but the \n doesn't work, what can I write for that works ? (`<br />` doesn't work too).

Comment: `$content =str_replace("&nbsp;", '<br>', $content);`

Comment: @soul No sorry, the "skip line" is erased... &nbsp is well erased, but the "skip line" too...

Comment: check now have updated

Comment: check using `echo nl2br($content );`

Comment: check for the $content if the <br> is displayed where you need by printing it using nl2br

Comment: @soul I think that's because Wordpress change <br> to &nbsp after updating post... :/ Because when I'm editing text, and I add <br> that's ok, skip line is fine, but after that removes the <br> too...

Comment: "<br/>" try using it

Comment: `<br>` is a line break, `&nbsp;` is a no-break space. They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Newlines in HTML are expressed through `<br >` or `<br/>`, not through `\n`.

`$content = str_replace("&nbsp;", '<br/>', $content);
echo nl2br($content);`

Answer (score 0):

`\n` doesn't represent a new line in HTML, so you won't see the line break when you echo the result. Either use `"<br />"` directly as the replacement, or use the default `nl2br()` PHP function to insert HTML line breaks before PHP line breaks e.g.

```
$sample = "testing a \n line break";
echo $sample;
// HTML output is:
"testing a  line break"

$sample2 = "testing a <br /> line break";
echo $sample2;
// HTML output is:
"testing a
 line break"

$sample3 = "testing a \n line break";
$sample3 = nl2br($sample3);
echo $sample3;
// HTML output is:
"testing a
 line break"
```

Comment: Ok, so can I use something like : 
$content =str_replace("&nbsp;", '\n', $content);
return nl2br($content); ????

Comment: or `$content = str_replace("&nbsp;", "<br />", $content);`

Comment: or `$content = nl2br(str_replace("&nbsp;", "\n", $content));` if you really wanted

Comment: the first :  $content =str_replace("&nbsp;", "<br />", $content); works fine for one skipping line, but if I use two skipping line, the two are erased.

Comment: <br /> is changed after posting to &nbsp;

Comment: I'd look at your wordpress PHP files then, I don't understand why it would replace a line break with a space...